# PKIX path building failed : I added certificate to carcert still failing

Tags: java, exception, keytool, sslhandshakeexception, pkix

I am facing this problem with PKIX path build failuer, this is what I have tried...

1. I went to the target URL that I am trying to reach

   ```
    (eg -> https://localdevchannel.master.info/Gate/CustomerManagement/rest/resources/search)
   ```

   I clicked on the "LOCK" icon and exported the certificate.
2. I ran below command...

   keytool -importcert -file sec.cer -storepass changeit -keystore "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.2/jdk-11.0.2/lib/security/cacerts" -alias secCert
3. The certificate got placed successfully. But I am still facing this issue. Please help what did I do wrong?

   ```
   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   ```

Answer (score 2):

ok,

You get this exception if your Certificate is expired, or does not exist in your store, or you updated another cacert file, and your java/and/or app is looking/using another.

1- Inspect your cacert file to actually see if the CERT has been added
with its alias there.

From inside your JDK/jre/bin , you can find the keytool.exe
You can call it like below to read the cacerts file:

```
susan@SE-00018098 /c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/bin

$ keytool.exe -list -keystore ../lib/security/cacerts
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 92 entries

digicertassuredidrootca, 2008-apr-16, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 05:63:B8:63:0D:62:D7:5A:BB:C8:AB:1E:4B:DF:B5:A8:99:B2:4D:43
trustcenterclass2caii, 2008-apr-29, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): AE:50:83:ED:7C:F4:5C:BC:8F:61:C6:21:FE:68:5D:79:42:21:15:6E
thawtepremiumserverca, 2009-dec-11, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): E0:AB:05:94:20:72:54:93:05:60:62:02:36:70:F7:CD:2E:FC:66:66
swisssignplatinumg2ca, 2008-okt-31, trustedCertEntry,
```

2- If it is, is it expired? Check the date.

3- Confirm whether your app/java runtime is using the cacert file
you just updated (Do you have multiple Java versions installed? What is your (Java_home)

======== Edited

If the certificate exists, and it is not expired, and you are 100% sure it is the right certificate, then probably your application/or container is not looking at the cacert file.

> Try the hack below:  I consider this as a hack, as you are hardcoding
> a path that may/not exist when you deploy on a different server.
>
> There are many ways of create your own truststore and keystore stores
> and having those in the app itself, then you can incorporate them in
> your code, but try it to just see if the rest of the code works.

Set the system property **before** your https connection code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "java_home_path/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
```

Replace with the correct path to cacerts file and try.

Comment: Helpful stackover flow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Comment: I have a Java_home : with path to jdk11 bin. (Hence no occurance of multiple java version)

Comment: I tried to open cacert file, not sure why the command was not working. keystore "path" -list was not working.

Comment: @horizon, I updated the answer.   Password is changeit

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, and keeo you posted. Did you face anything like this? Just curious?

Comment: yes @horizon at work, everytime a certificate gets expired mostly :)

Comment: Hello @Susan, I check the keystore, I have entry of cert ---->>> seccert, Dec 1, 2020, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): D8:12:E9:D8:C5:8A:70:8C:0E:B0:5B:77:AA:A7:B4:CD:4A:80:4B:52:69:97:0B:FB:C2:D7:F3:77:92:B2:1E:F8

Comment: The way how I generated this cer file is that correct? See ultimately I have to reach a URL, where I will send a POST req, so I opened it on my chrome browser and exported the cer using the LOCK icon.

Comment: Then in this case if you can see the cert is there and is not expired, I suggest you show some code/or explain how your app is doing the https connections towards this website?   @horizon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225415/discussion-between-susan-mustafa-and-horizon).

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution after I went true all the answers, and no one helped.
I don't know why, but I change myprive.key  and myepublic.crt just change to myprivate.key.pem and mypublic.pem

So just find out how to covert .key and .crt into .pem

After that, it workde perfectly.

I needed it for sonarqube and some QA tests